# Angular 5 HttpClient ignores Set-Cookie header from wordpress REST api post response

Tags: wordpress, angular, rest, cookies, httpclient

I've googled a lot but I don't seem to be able to find a definitive answer to my problem. Lots of *similar* situations/solutions but none is working for me.

My set up is as follows:

**Environment**: XAMP, Wordpress 4.9 and Angular Material Design running on top of Angular 5

**Back-end (REST API server)**:
I have a fully working Wordpress setup, running smoothly at address: http://localhost/~XXXX/wordpress.
I intend to use *only* the back-end, in order to feed data to clients through the built-in json REST API interface, for which I've set up a custom/test end-point like this:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {

    register_rest_route('cookie-test/v1', 'set', [
      'methods' => 'POST',
      'callback' => function () {
          setcookie('cookieKey', $_POST['cookieValue'], time()+60*60*24*30);
          return [
            'responseKey' => 'responseValue',
          ];
      },
    ]);
});
```

Actually, what I'm trying to implement is some sort of cookie-based authentication for the front end, which *is not* wordpress based!
This (pseudo)code is basically a test bed in order to check proper cookie functionality/exchange between backend and frontend.

**Frontend**: (part of it)

```
// auth.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService
{
    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
    )
    {
    }

    cookieTest() {
        return this.http.post(
            'http://localhost/~XXXX/wordpress/wp-json/cookie-test/v1/set',
            {cookieValue: 'randomValue'},
            {
                observe: 'response', // Full response instead of the body only
                withCredentials: true, // Send cookies
            }
        );
    }
}

// login.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Component({
    selector   : 'login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls  : ['./login.component.scss'],
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit
{
    loginForm: FormGroup;
    loginFormErrors: any;

    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private authService: AuthService,
        private router: Router,
    )
    {
        this.loginFormErrors = {
            email   : {},
            password: {}
        };
    }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            email   : ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
            password: ['', Validators.required],
        });
    }

    onCookieTest()
    {
        this.authService.cookieTest()
            .subscribe(
                response => {
                    const keys: string[] = response.headers.keys();
                    console.log(keys);
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error => {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            );
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM**:
The front end can reach the wordpress REST API end-point, which in turn responds correctly to the angular 'post' request, ***but***... but the cookie is not set in the browser!

I can see from the debugger console of the browser that the Set-Cookie header in the POST response is there, with the correct fields, but apparently the browser (or Angular's HttpClient?) is completely ignoring it!

Googling around I haven't been able to find anything about the pair <Wordpress REST API>/Angular5. All sort of back-ends (ruby, laravel, java, C#, etc.) but nothing about Wordpress with Angular5's HttpClient.

These are the headers:

**Request (OPTIONS)**

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers  content-type
Referer http://localhost:4200/auth/login
Origin  http://localhost:4200
Accept  */*
User-Agent  ...
Access-Control-Request-Method   POST
```

**Response (OPTIONS)**

```
Transfer-Encoding   Identity
Connection  Keep-Alive
X-Powered-By    PHP/7.0.14
Access-Control-Allow-Methods    OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
Access-Control-Expose-Headers   X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages
Vary    Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Headers    x-wp-nonce, Authorization, Content-Type
Server  Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) PHP/7.0.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8zg
Content-Type    application/json; charset=UTF-8
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials    true
Date    Thu, 12 Apr 2018 19:20:43 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://localhost:4200
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
X-Content-Type-Options  nosniff
X-Robots-Tag    noindex
Link    <http://localhost/~XXXX/wordpress/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Allow   POST
```

**Request (POST)**

```
DNT 1
Content-Type    application/json
Referer http://localhost:4200/auth/login
Accept  application/json, text/plain, */*
User-Agent  ...
Origin  http://localhost:4200
```

**Response (POST)**

```
Transfer-Encoding   Identity
Connection  Keep-Alive
X-Powered-By    PHP/7.0.14
Access-Control-Allow-Methods    OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
Set-Cookie  cookieKey=randomValue; expires=Sat, 12-May-2018 19:20:53 GMT; Max-Age=2592000
Access-Control-Expose-Headers   X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages
Vary    Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Headers    x-wp-nonce, Authorization, Content-Type
Server  Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) PHP/7.0.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8zg
Content-Type    application/json; charset=UTF-8
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials    true
Date    Thu, 12 Apr 2018 19:20:52 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://localhost:4200
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
X-Content-Type-Options  nosniff
Link    <http://localhost/~XXXX/wordpress/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
X-Robots-Tag    noindex
Allow   POST
```

Thank you in advance for any help/hint

Comment: try   setting the path `setcookie('cookieKey', $_POST['cookieValue'], time()+60*60*24*30, '/')`

Comment: @David BINGO!!! If you post your comment as answer, I will mark it as the correct one!!! Thank you very much David!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the path (e.g. root path) in your backend

```
setcookie('cookieKey', $_POST['cookieValue'], time()+60*60*24*30, '/')
```

If you don't specify the path when you set the cookie, it'll only be available on the current path (`.../wp-json/cookie-test/v1/set`), which means that the cookie won't get sent to your backend in future requests if you try a different path on that domain

Comment: Thank you again, David. Actually, my struggle is "against" wordpress. If I try to set the cookie like this (which is what wordpress does) `setcookie('cookieKey', $_POST['cookieValue'], time()+60*60*24*30, '/localhost/~XXXX/wordpress/plugins');` the cookie is not visible on port 4200. It works only if you are using wordpress' frontend, which is what I'm trying to avoid. Thank you

Comment: Thank you, David, thanks to your hint I'm managing to get trough... Thanks